# How do I pass a map as a Helm tpl string?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to populate the annotations on a service which is templated like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    {{- if .Values.service.annotations }}
    {{ tpl .Values.service.annotations . | nindent 4 | trim }}
    {{- end }}
```

(rest omitted for brevity.)

I tried to populate the `service.annotations` like this in my values.yaml:

```yaml
service:
  annotations:
    foo: my-foo
    bar: 6
    baz: false
```

... but Helm errored out with `[ERROR] templates/: template: my-chart/templates/service.yaml:20:18: executing "my-chart/templates/service.yaml" at <.Values.service.annotations>: wrong type for value; expected string; got map[string]interface {}`

I tried reading the [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) for the `tpl` function but they just showed examples for how to interpolate a string from a different variable, or how to pass values from an external file.

How do I set the annotations on this service? I don't have any control over the template.

Comment: With that construction, `annotations` must be a YAML string.  You say you don't have any control over the template; are you trying to write this chart, or just deploy it using a custom set of values?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy a chart with a custom set of values. _Technically_ I've wrapped the chart as a subchart, but at the end of the day, the template is as I wrote above and I'm just trying to populate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

update

You need to understand the essence of the problem, my previous answer is the style required for the final rendering, based on this, you just need to understand the usage of `tpl` and try to render the template as written before.

[helm tpl](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function)

values.yaml

```yaml
service:
  annotations: "{{ toYaml .Values.service.fields | trim }}"
  fields:
    foo: my-foo
    bar: 6
    baz: false
```

template

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    {{- if .Values.service.annotations }}
    {{ tpl .Values.service.annotations . | nindent 4 | trim }}
    {{- end }}
...
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    bar: 6
    baz: false
    foo: my-foo
...
```

---

As David Maze said.
In service.yaml, `annotations` must be a YAML string.

You may try
tempaltes/service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  {{- if .Values.service.annotations }}
  annotations:  
    {{ toYaml .Values.service.annotations | nindent 4 | trim }}
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I have no control over the template. It is as written.